# Dropbox settings have a font problem

Tags: fonts, dropbox

I'm running Dropbox in Kubuntu 20.04 on a Dell laptop with a very high default resolution.  When I click on the Dropbox icon on the taskbar, the menu comes up in an incredibly tiny font. How can I fix that?